# Apply/Use a function with several divs with the same class JQUERY

Tags: jquery, function, class, arguments

I ,m using a little script to detect if two elements collides.

```
function collision($yo, $obstaculo) {
var x1 = $yo.offset().left;
var y1 = $yo.offset().top;
var h1 = $yo.outerHeight(true);
var w1 = $yo.outerWidth(true);
var b1 = y1 + h1;
var r1 = x1 + w1;
var x2 = $obstaculo.offset().left;
var y2 = $obstaculo.offset().top;
var h2 = $obstaculo.outerHeight(true);
var w2 = $obstaculo.outerWidth(true);
var b2 = y2 + h2;
var r2 = x2 + w2;

if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
return true;
```

}

My problem its that I dont know how to use the function with all the divs with the class name '.obstacle'. Right know I´m calling the function like this:

```
collision($('#character'),$('.obstacle'));
```

EDIT: I have make a test in jfiddle using .each, but seems not to work. For some reason only retrieve the las element, and it always return true:

http://jsfiddle.net/Osaka_lime/jV9Ls/27/

Like always, sorry for my terrible English and Thanx!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution calling with .each my function collision:

```
pum = false;
      $(".obstaculo").each(function () { pum = pum || collision($('#character'), $(this), dir) });
```

You can see it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jV9Ls/29/

Good Night!

Answer (score 0):

Because $obstaculo could have more than one object in it, you will have to iterate through all of the divs in the collection and check each one. Using jQuery, you would have to do something like:

```
function collision($yo, $obstaculo) {
   var x1 = $yo.offset().left;
   var y1 = $yo.offset().top;
   var h1 = $yo.outerHeight(true);
   var w1 = $yo.outerWidth(true);
   var b1 = y1 + h1;
   var r1 = x1 + w1;

   $obstaculo.each(function () {
      var x2 = $(this).offset().left;
      var y2 = $(this).offset().top;
      var h2 = $(this).outerHeight(true);
      var w2 = $(this).outerWidth(true);
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;
      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
   });

   return true;
}
```

Note that I haven't tested this code but hopefully you can use this as an example and it can give you an idea on where to go next.

Comment: Thanx for your help, I´m trying to use your .each function but seems that always retrive true, you can see my code in this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/Osaka_lime/jV9Ls/27/

Comment: Ok, I have found a .each  solution, yo can see it in this jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jV9Ls/29/

Thanx for your help.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner but glad you found a solution!